# DevExpress and missed reference

Tags: c#, reference, devexpress, .net-2.0

When I am trying to change references in my project from **DevExpress 9.2** to **DevExpress 11.2** for all of them, I am getting follow exceptions in one of my classes:

> <...> The type or namespace name 'DevExpress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) <...>
>   <...>The type or namespace name 'LayoutControl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) <...>

I am using following references:

> DevExpress.Data
>   DevExpress.Utils
>   DevExpress.XtraBars
>   DevExpress.XtraEditors
>   DevExpress.XtraGrid
>   DevExpress.XtraLayout
>   DevExpress.XtraNavBar

When I am using v9.2 – everything is OK, but when I am changing references – I am getting following underlining:

> using ***DevExpress***.XtraLayout;
>
> public static string GetLayout(***LayoutControl*** layoutControl)

So, how can I change that references properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found: **DevExpress 11.2** just not working with **.NET 2.0**. If you have such problem, you need to change your project's target framework at least to **.NET 3.5**, or, of course, you can just forget about **DevExpress 11.2**, and use older versions of it. :)